# I can´t access to DATA directory

Tags: android, eclipse

The data directory of my phone will not let me access the adb shell nor, nor DDMS eclipse and I need to see my database that is within him, as I can fix it??

Comment: You want to query your application's database from your machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to root the device to see the data directory. You can see that in an emulator though .

Comment: although via root u can gain access to your data directory which will bring some kind of convenience while debugging apps, rooting a device is highly discouraged if the app security and integrity are in your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your device is flashed with the usr OS　image, in usr image device manufacturer has constrain the file access permission on user data, so you can not list this contents of /data path under eclipse and shell.

You can follow the official flash guide [url](http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html)  to flash device, if your device is Nexus and compatible device.

You can "Root" your device, google it for your device you will get mount of advice on "how to root".